# How to search in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, search, for-loop, dictionary

I am trying to search in a dictionary.
I have 2 dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
Dictionary<int, int> temp = new Dictionary<int, int>()
```

then ive populated this dictionary with:

```
dict.Add(123, "");
dict.Add(124, ""); //and so on
```

then i want to loop though this dictionary and recall the key and add that to the other dictionary

```
for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++)
{
   if (dict[i] == "")
   {
        temp.Add(dict[dict.ElementAt(i).Key],0);
        dict[dict.ElementAt(i).Value] = "Moved";
   }
}
```

i shall be doing other things inside this forloop so i cannot change that to a foreach loop. I am trying to check if the value of the Dictionary dict is empty then take the Key and copy the key value to the temp dictionary, but i am getting errors.
Please help :)

the problem im trying to solve is that i want to be able to search the dict dictionary for for a value with "" and take the key and store it in another dictionary temp (which will later on hold a second value). i need to do this in a for-loop as i want to be able to go back by changing the value of i.

i want to be able to use i to select both the key and value from the dict dictionary.

The errors i was getting was simply converting from string to int, i cannot get it to even store the key from dict into an int variable.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: _"but i am getting errors"_ care to share those?

Comment: If your keys are sequential (which is what the for loop assumes), then `Dictionary` is not really the optimal container. Just use a list/array.

Comment: are you adding to this dictionary keys from 0 or did you start on 123?

Comment: You can enumerate the actual keys of a `Dictionary` through the `Keys` property.

Comment: Why is `temp` a dictionary? It should be a `List<int>` with all keys in the other dictionary where the value is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put a value in the temp dictionary.  I chose 0.

```
        Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        Dictionary<int, int> temp = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        dict.Add(123, "");
        dict.Add(124, ""); //and so on

        int[] keys = dict.Keys.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dict[keys[i]] == "")
            {
                temp.Add(keys[i],0);
                dict[keys[i]] = "Moved";
            }
        }
```

Comment: your solution has fixed it thanks, it was the addition of the keys array that helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
List<int> temp = new List<int>();


dict.Add(123, "");
dict.Add(124, ""); //and so on

foreach (int key in dict.Keys.ToList())
{
            if (dict[key] == "")
            {
                temp.Add(key);
                dict[key] = "Moved";
            }
        }
}
```

*
First, notice `temp` is a *List*, not a *Dictionary*, since you're just adding the keys, no **key => value** (this can be changed if you can better explain why you need this as a dictionary)...
Second, notice I used `dict.Keys` to get all the keys in the dictionary. I also used `ToList()` so it can work in the foreach loop...

Answer (score 0):

are you getting a compile error for the dictionary definition

```
Dictionary<int, int> temp = new Dictionary<int, temp>(); // int, temp?
```

if so,

```
Dictionary<int, int> temp = new Dictionary<int, int>(); // int, int
```

?

or, you're getting an error with this:

```
 temp.Add(dict[dict.ElementAt(i).Key]);
```

because you're adding just a key, with no value.  it would be something like

```
 temp.Add(i, dict[i]); ?
```

if you're just using temp to hold the key values, you don't want a Dictionary, you probably HashSet (only keys, no keys+values)

if you explain exactly what you're trying to solve, this is probably something you can do trivially with a single linq statement?

Comment: edited my question to try and make it more clear what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why is `temp` a dictionary? I would use a `List<int>` with all keys of the dictionary with an empty(null?) value.

```
List<int> keysWithEmptyValuesInDictionary = dict
    .Where(kvp => string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value))
    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
    .ToList();
foreach (int key in keysWithEmptyValuesInDictionary)
{
    dict[key] = "moved";
}
```